# Adding custom options to my opencart product

Tags: php, opencart

Well I have developed an open cart website and now I want some custom options with the product information

For example I want to buy some icecream.

Custom options would be lets say 3 different flavors.

Vanilla/Strawberry/Chocolate

For that also each flavor would have individual options. Lets say i want to buy vanilla then i have to buy a cone. If i want to buy strawberry then i have to buy a bar and if i want to buy chocolate then i have to buy a cup.

Its same as in buying a dreamweaver. If i buy a professional level dreamweaver then i would have to specify how many users and so forth and would have to purchase a license as well. Same as that.

I didnt found any options to add such feature in the admin panel. The only feature I found was to add the attribute.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about dependent options, then this is not a feature of OpenCart. By default, options are unaware of each other, so If `Option X = 1`, `Option Y` will not vary based on that choice, and vice versa. There is an [extension available (commercial)](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5214) that does what you want